# Summation Closed form for floor$\left(\log_n\right)$

Tags: summation, logarithms, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The closed sum for the floors of logs of consecutive integers is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \lfloor \log_2i\rfloor = n\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor-2^{\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor+1}+\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor+2$$

This formula works for $\log_2$, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to work for all bases.

I tried executing this and as you can see it works for base 2:

```
<?php

$sum = 0;
$n = 200;

$base = 2;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
    $sum += floor(log($i, $base));

echo $sum . "\n";

echo $n * floor(log($n, $base)) - pow($base, floor(log($n, $base)) + 1) + floor(log($n, $base)) + 2;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/6c290992fcd057):

```
1153
1153
```

However, once I change the base, it [no longer works](https://eval.in/private/10ef70011c9387).

What is the correct closed sum for floors of logs in any base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to calculate
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor\log_a i\rfloor
$$
in an integer base $a$ (non-integer is similar but more complicated and needs care). For $a^m\leq i<a^{m+1}$ you have $\lfloor\log_a i\rfloor=m$. Then there are $a^{m}(a-1)$ integers involved in this interval. Suppose $a^N\leq n<a^{N+1}$, i.e. $N=\lfloor\log_a n\rfloor$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor\log_a i\rfloor=N(n-a^N+1)+(a-1)\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} ja^j
$$
The sum is calculated as
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} ja^j=\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}-\frac{a^{N+1}}{(a-1)^2}+\frac{Na^N}{a-1}
$$
So
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor\log_a i\rfloor=\lfloor\log_a n\rfloor(n+1)+
\frac{a}{a-1}-\frac{a^{\lfloor\log_a n\rfloor+1}}{a-1}
$$
which reduces to you expression for $a=2$.